Disable Execution of Extra Code for a HEAD request
My website uses GeoLocation, and other APIs to server my users with better experience. In the access logs and bespoke debugging code, I see quite a lot HEAD requests that are made to the website. Upon further debugging, I see all of my code and plugins are executed on HEAD requests too.
The main problem is that due to high frequency of page visits made to the site, greater than 120 per minute by a single IP, the API calls return HTTP error 429. These may be GET requests or possibly HEAD requests, which I am not sure of. What I am sure is that they are spam requests and site abusers that cause problems.
In order to reduce extra processing on the server, and avoid executing external API calls, I want a PHP check to stop execution whenever a HEAD request is made.
My question is, can we detect a HEAD request in PHP and respond accordingly.
I am testing using this function:
get_headers("http://example.com")
getallheaders()
This doesn't mention the REQUEST METHOD
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] => 'GET'
This always have GET as the request method. Shouldn't there be HEAD?

I just did a test with curl --head, and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] was HEAD, not GET.

If the rate limiting is being done in your webserver, checking for this in PHP will not help. You need to check for it in the webserver.

@Barmar thank you for your input. I have enabled rate limiting on my server which appears to have solved the issue.
